# Blackberry JDE installer can't find java

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I am attempting to install the Blackberry JDE on Windows 7.  I have java installed and the JAVA_HOME variable is set to the install directory of java, however the installer tells me that Java cannot be found and I need ot download and install it before I can continue.

[image]

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: Are you running 32 or 64 bit windows 7? Do you have 32 or 64 bit Java installed?

Comment: @Richard 64 bit on both counts

Comment: have u set your java bin path in to your system ?

Comment: Yah, bin there, done that. Unless you really need to have 64 bit Java for some other reason the best way forward is probably to remove the 64 bit Java, install 32 bit Java and start again.

Comment: No need to remove the 64 bit Java. I have the same configuration as you do. Just install the 32 bit Java version (in addition to the 64 bit Java you already have). According to BlackBerry plugin requirements **64-bit Windows versions require 32-bit Java® and Eclipse**

Comment: @Richard please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.  The problem was that BB JDE requires 32 bit java.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BlackBerry Eclipse Plugin, even running on 64 bit Windows versions requires 32 bit JDE. You can get both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of JDE to work on one system if you need to. If, like me, the only requirement for Java is for BlackBerry development having only one JDE to worry about is a lot simpler.